# SQL syntax to increment field when double key is duplicate

Tags: mysql

I am building an application quite similar to jsfiddle.net, handling saving and forking of some kind.

I have a SQL table 'url' of 3 columns : the code of a given saved state, the version (1, 2, 3 etc.) of it, and the id of the saved state as is indexed in another table.
Say I have the code of a saved state, and want to fork it (create a new version of it). How can I tell MySQL to INSERT a row in 'url' with the same code as provided, but a version number equal to the last version number used for this code + 1?

In short, this is the opposite of a ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. I want that, on duplicate key, the insert be slightly different than the duplicated key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a `code` of 'foo' and an `id` of 1:

```
INSERT INTO url (code, version, id)
     SELECT 'foo', COALESCE(MAX(version) + 1, 1), 1 -- is 'foo' already there?
       FROM url 
      WHERE code = 'foo';
```

Comment: wait, what would be the id inserted then ?

Comment: my bad, it works perfect. is there a way for me to know what the COALESCE(MAX(version) + 1, 1) returned ?

Comment: @Cystack, you'd have to issue a new query to determine that.